# Como salvar id do click no botão numa sessão PHP?

Tags: php, session

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
<tr id="teste">
      <?php echo '<form id="teste" action="banco.php" method="post"><td><input  id="bike'.$fetch['referenciageral'].'" name="bike'.$fetch['referenciageral'].'" onchange="this.form.submit()"  type="checkbox" value="on" '.$fetch['checkbox'].' class="confirmacoes"><a href="banco.php"> </a></td></form>';?>
       <?php  echo '<td >'.utf8_encode($fetch['referenciageral']).'</td>';?>
        <?php  echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['nivel']).'</td>';  ?>
        <?php echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['numero_item']).'</td>';?>
<?php   echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['material']).'</td>';?>
 <?php echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['descricao']).'</td>';?>


 <?php echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['qtdeng']).'</td>';?>
<?php  echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['qtdfalt']).'</td>';?>
<?php  echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['OBSERVACAO']).'</td>';?>
<?php  echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['PDF_PT'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="'.$fetch['LINK_TCD#LINK_PDF_PT_IMAGE'].'"  /></a></td>';?>
 <?php echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['PDF_IT'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="'.$fetch['LINK_TCD#LINK_PDF_IT_IMAGE'].'"  /></a></td>';?>
 <?php echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['LINK_JT'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="'.$fetch['LINK_TCD#LINK_JT_IMAGE'].'"  /></a></td>';?>
 <?php echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['LINK_DXF'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="'.$fetch['LINK_TCD#LINK_DXF_IMAGE'].'"  /></a></td>';?>
  <?php echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['LINK_RAR'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="'.$fetch['LINK_TCD#LINK_RAR_IMAGE'].'"  /></a></td>';?>
 <?php echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['LINK_ZIP'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="'.$fetch['LINK_TCD#LINK_ZIP_IMAGE'].'"  /></a></td>';?>
  <?php echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['LINK_EPJ'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="'.$fetch['LINK_TCD#LINK_EPJ_IMAGE'].'"  /></a></td>';?>


 <?php echo '<form id="teste2" action="preencheformulario.php" method="post"><td><input type="submit" id="dev'.$fetch['referenciageral'].'" name="dev'.$fetch['referenciageral'].'"
onclick="reply_click(this.id)" ></td></form>';?>
```

E tenho o script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    alert(clicked_id);
<?php session_start(); $_SESSION['teste'] = this.id?>
}
</script>
```

Quero que o `id` que aparece no `alert` seja armazenado numa sessão PHP.

Fiz como segue acima, mas não funciona, a sessão fica vazia.

Answer (score 2):

Você está misturando PHP com Javascript.

Primeiro você precisa entender duas coisas:

- PHP é uma linguagem server-side - que roda do lado do servidor.
- Javascript é uma linguagem cliente-side - que roda do lado do cliente.

Em outros palavras, o PHP é executado no servidor (geralmente o Apache) para gerar o conteúdo HTML que vai ser exibido no seu site.

O Javascript, por sua vez, é uma linguagem que vai atuar em cima desse resultado HTML.

Sendo assim, não é possível afetar a variável de um código PHP através da intervenção do Javascript, pois os dois atuam  em momentos diferentes.

O fato de você poder escrever Javascript, HTML e PHP juntos, não significam que você pode misturar a funcionalidade de um com outro.

Explicado isso, vamos para a próxima situação:

Não tem como escrever a variável javascript diretamente na função PHP. O que você pode fazer é enviar uma requisição pelo Javascript ao seu script PHP , para ele processar aquelas informações.

Você pode usar o `$.ajax` do jQuery, por exemplo:

```
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'salvar_informacao.php', 
        data: {clicked_id: clicked_id},
        success: function () {
            // Quando a requisição for concluída
        }
    });
}
```

No `salvar_informacao.php`, você deve colocar:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['clicked_id'] = $_POST['clicked_id'];
```

Porém, isso vai depender muito do que você quer fazer.

Dependendo da operação, você pode simplesmente usar `localStorage` ou mesmo um `cookie` para resolver o problema. Este último pode ter o valor acessado pelo PHP através da variável `$_COOKIE`.

Comment: A frase "não é possível misturar código Javascript com PHP" ficou ambígua. Na verdade é possível `let appName = "<?php echo "My App" ?>"`, o que não é possível é alterar os valores da variável *PHP* após o processamento.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr é verdade, no contexto dele, realmente não é possível, mas tem que explicar melhor. Vou editar