# Acessar Variável local em JavaScript e armazenas em variável PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Boa noite!

Como eu poderia armazenar os dados da variável "teste" em "$variavelphp". Da maneira como esta o código hoje a variável "teste" não esta acessível.

Caso não seja possível como eu poderia acessar o valor da variável "teste" em "teste2" em outra parte do código.

```
                var ref = firebase.database().ref('Profissionais').orderByChild('Nome');


                //var u = 0;

        ref.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
            var profissional = snapshot.val();
            if (profissional.provider == "usuarios" || profissional.provider == "Facebook" || profissional.provider == "Firebase" || profissional.provider == "Usuarios") {
                 teste =  "<tr><td>" + snapshot.key + "</td><td>" + profissional.Nome + "</td><td>" + profissional.Email + "</td><td>" + profissional.provider + "</td><td><a href='usuario.php?id=" + snapshot.key + "' class='btn btn-round btn-fill btn-info'>Consultar</a></td></tr>";


            }



            });



</script>


    <?php
        $variavelphp = "<script>document.write(teste)</script>";

        ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

var teste2 = teste;

alert(teste2);



</script>
```

Comment: Não é possível. [**Recomendo**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25136/igualar-vari%C3%A1vel-php-a-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-javascript)

Comment: Praticamente o  mesmo problema que respondi aqui ontem: [Salvar ID do click do botão numa sessão PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/338529/como-salvar-id-do-click-no-bot%C3%A3o-numa-session-php/338595#338595)

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia, amigo.
Sugiro, após pegar o dados do Firebase, você fazer um post/get para uma página em PHP e pegar o dado da requisição em si.

Se for GET, seria assim:

```
$variavel = $_GET['teste'];
```

Se for POST:

```
$variavel = $_POST['teste'];
```

Dessa forma, você consegue passar as informações de Javascript para o PHP. Mas, só com requisições: **POST, GET, PUT,** etc..

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Olá, jovem. Bem-vindo ao Stackoverflow. Isso não responde ao que foi perguntando. Parece que o Autor da Pergunta está tentando acessar uma variável Javascript pelo PHP, isso não é possivel e, como já foi indicado acima nos comentários, existem várias respostas no site sobre o assunto.